# Can we create DbContext with two models

Tags: c#, sql-server, model, asp.net-mvc-5, datacontext

I'm new to Asp.net and created a web application using MVC5 in Asp.Net. And I have a quick question like can we create DbContext with two models(As shown in below image).

[image]

From above code, I can able to apply CRUD operations to Employee model.. But I'm getting this exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.User
> Details'

For UserDetails model, and I'm suspecting that it is happening only because of two models in one DbContext.. Is my approach is correct or not?

please help me..

Comment: Does a table "dbo.User" exist? Maybe you also need to add it to the context

Comment: Certainly you can add more than one `DbSet` in a `DbContext` class, as long as the entity type name is exist. Which CRUD operation throwing exception?

Comment: @user2657943 yes it exists with table name "User Details" ;

@Tetsuya Yamamoto
I'm getting exception with `await db.SaveChangesAsync();` after adding data using `db.UserDetails.Add(userDetails);`

Comment: Open UserDetails class and put a `[Table("YourTableName")]` above it. If it doesn't work try running a migration. I bet **EF** will create the correct table for you.

Comment: If you have overriding `OnModelCreating` method inside context class, you can try `modelBuilder.Entity<UserDetails>().ToTable("UserDetails");` after `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();`, then use `Database.SetInitializer<EmployeeContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<EmployeeContext>());`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be to do with pluralizing database names. In your EmployeeContext class try

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)  {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: Where I should create this method? Inside controller??

Comment: No, inside the EmployeeContext class. 

There's an example in MS docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

It's a big page, but search for Create the Database Context.

EDIT I've added a screen shot of the relevant code.

Comment: Still facing the same issue :(

Comment: You may have a mispelling somewhere. 
There is a space inbetween User and Details in the error message.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.User Details'
Should be:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.UserDetails'


Can you post the code which is throwing the excepetion?

Comment: I have given [Table("User Details")] for my model class. 
It is throwing an error with the same name as User Details... Even I tried as UserDetails also.

Comment: There is a space between User and Details, change to [Table("UserDetails")]

Comment: Have a look at the table in the database, is there a space there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138509/discussion-between-veswanth-raju-and-eric-yeoman).